# Android TextInputLayout Password toggle not visible in new support library

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have compiled with following design library and it is displaying password **HIDE/SHOW** button at the right of **`EditText`**

> compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_password_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_micro"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="password" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

like:

[image]

after updating to

> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

Its not visible, Why? Is there any bug?

Please guide.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `TextInputLayout` password toggle is now disabled by default to avoid unnecessarily overwriting developer-specified end drawables. It may be manually enabled via the [`passwordToggleEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.attr.html#passwordToggleEnabled) XML attribute.

from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: You are welcome. For the same situation, I have checked reversion history and it helps both of us.

Answer (score 10):

I smashed my head with this one for hours.

From the release notes:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#

> Fixed issues: The TextInputLayout password toggle is now disabled by
>   default to avoid unnecessarily overwriting developer-specified end
>   drawables. It may be manually enabled via the passwordToggleEnabled
>   XML attribute.

So to have it back, you have to:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
    ...
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          ....
          ....
          .... />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is disabled in 25.0.1. If you want it, you need to manually enable it

Check reference [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

> The TextInputLayout password toggle is now disabled by default to
>   avoid unnecessarily overwriting developer-specified end drawables. It
>   may be manually enabled via the passwordToggleEnabled XML attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The **[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)** password toggle is now disabled by default to avoid unnecessarily overwriting developer-specified end drawables. It may be manually enabled via the [`passwordToggleEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.attr.html#passwordToggleEnabled) XML attribute.

### [see revision for 25.0.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Note : Every developer must see the revision document.

Answer (score 2):

Add endIconMode to Custom for adding drawable end for a textinputlayout.

`<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   app:endIconMode="custom"
   app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_tick_grey"
   ....
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>`

Answer (score 1):

**Using This**

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"  in TextInputLayout
```

**and change dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

[Setting up Gradle for api 26 (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500176/setting-up-gradle-for-api-26-android/45874643#45874643)

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textInputLayout2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/box_layout_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/box_layout_margin_right"
                android:padding="@dimen/text_input_padding"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/edit_input_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true">
                </EditText>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```