# Android TextInputLayout PasswordToggle Not Working

Tags: android, material-design

I am having a trouble displaying the password using `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`.
I am using Material Design, I have dependencies of support:design and material design, I even tried endIcon password_toggle. But when I click to the toggle button it simply does not work.

My Layout is below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginPasswordLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/lock_2"
            app:startIconTint="@color/black"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/black">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:elevation="20dp"
                android:background="@color/transparentWhite"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="15"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: where is your code? check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098475/android-textinputlayout-password-toggle-not-visible-in-new-support-library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TextInputLayout Password Toggle Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037679/textinputlayout-password-toggle-listener)

Comment: I thought that passwordToggleEnabled should do the rest of the job... Thank you, i will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:elevation` attribute is not suitable for `TextInputEditText` and you need to remove it and it will work.

After removing `android:elevation="20dp"`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/lock_2"
        app:startIconTint="@color/black"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/black">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/transparentWhite"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="15"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```